# Can the duplicate linked question be changed to a more appropriate answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, questions, duplicates

In this question: [Do the effects of spells granted by items require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/188385/do-the-effects-of-spells-granted-by-items-require-concentration) I asked about items that grant named spell effects, not casting spells from items or items that give a spell-like effect without a spell involved.

The linked duplicate question: [Do magic item spells require concentration?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99199/do-magic-item-spells-require-concentration) only answers items that directly cast spells from them, or grant a spell-like effect without casting a spell at all. It does not answer the question I proposed which is when an item gives a named spells effect without directly casting that spell. Neither this question, nor answer are related to what I asked and are not helpful.

I would like to change the linked answer to this question: [Do potions use concentration for their effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69926/do-potions-use-concentration-for-their-effects) which does address the question I asked, albeit it was only answered after I asked my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I put the change through

I went ahead and just updated the duplicate list to include both questions as dupe targets. To me, they both seem like good candidates for being called a duplicate so I went ahead and just added the one you wanted to the list

Comment: I disagree that they are both suitable but the change that I wanted was put through so I'll take that as good enough. Thank you!